# Different Behavior found when compile option - keep-generated-actionscript (SDK 4.6.0)

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.6, bindable

Is [Bindable] meta tag need to be added in the subclass if the [Bindable] property is overridden?

### ParentClass

[Bindable] 
public get enabled: Boolean
public set enabled(value:Boolean)

### SubClass

public override set enabled(value:Boolean)

I tried to compile the above code using SDK 4.6.0.
If the meta data [Bindable] is missing, the change of the property - enabled cannot be detected if the property - enabled is modified.
Problem found only when compiler option - keep-generated-actionscript = true is set.
If the compiler option - keep-generated-actionscript = false, the problem cannot be found, the change of property can be detected even the meta data [Bindable] is missing.

Do you know why???